# Passing variable between jobs in Azure Pipeline with empty result

Tags: variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am writing an azure pipeline yml requesting to pass variables between jobs but the variables are not passing through. however, it wasn't successful and it returns an empty variable.

here is my pipeline:

```
jobs:
  - job: UpdateVersion
    variables:
      terraformRepo: ${{ parameters.terraformRepo }}
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        persistCredentials: true
      - checkout: ${{ parameters.terraformRepo }}
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: PerformVerUpdate
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscriptionName }}
          scriptType: bash
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
            echo Step 3 result
            echo "Reponame $Reponame"
            echo "notify $notify"
            echo "pullRequestId $pullRequestId"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pullRequestId;isOutput=true;]$pullRequestId"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Reponame;isOutput=true;]$Reponame"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=notify;isOutput=true;]true"
        Name: PerformVerUpdate

  - job: SlackSuccessNotification
    dependsOn: UpdateVersion
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.UpdateVersion.outputs['PerformVerUpdate.notify'], 'true'))
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    variables:
      - group: platform-alerts-webhooks
      - name: notify_J1
        value: $[ dependencies.UpdateVersion.outputs['PerformVerUpdate.notify'] ]
      - name: pullRequestId_J1
        value: $[ dependencies.UpdateVersion.outputs['PerformVerUpdate.pullRequestId'] ]
      - name: Reponame_J1
        value: $[ dependencies.UpdateVersion.outputs['PerformVerUpdate.Reponame'] ]
    steps:
      - task: AzurePowerShell@5
        displayName: Slack Notification
        inputs:
          pwsh: true
          azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureSubscriptionName }}
          ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
          TargetAzurePs: LatestVersion
          inline: |
            write-host  "Reponame $(Reponame_J1)"
            write-host  "pullRequest $(pullRequestId_J1)"
```

I've tried so many different syntax for it but the variables are still not able to pass through between both jobs - e.g. The condition is passing Null result to second job "(Expanded: and(True, eq(Null, 'true'))". Could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly 'Name' should be 'name' in lowercase

```
Name: PerformVerUpdate
```

The rest of syntax seems fine(I have tested it on Bash task because I do not have Azure subscription).

If renaming 'Name' does not help I suppose the problem may be that your Bash task is running within AzureCLI@2 task.
Maybe as workaround you could add new Bash task right after AzureCLI@2 and try to set there output variable for next job?

Comment: The answer is correct. The only required modification is to use `name` in a lowercase to define the symbolic task alias; the AzureCLI task is able to output variables and pass them to the subsequent jobs.